# How do I sort my ListAdapter by Difficulty - Easy, Medium and then Hard?

Tags: android, sorting, android-listview, menuitem, listadapter

I've got this code below in order to sort my ListView items depending on the name of the item:

```
case R.id.menu_order_name:
        adapter.sort(new Comparator<Shop>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Shop arg0, Shop arg1) {
                return arg0.getName().compareTo(arg1.getName());
            }
        });
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
```

I have a slight issue in the fact that I also want to have an ActionBar menu option to sort by the difficulty too: the difficulties being easy, medium and hard. The problem is, if I use the same sort method, it sorts them by easy, hard, medium...as they are in the alphabet. Can anybody help me in setting it so that it compares them to the actual difficulty level, from easy to hard and how would I specify this order?

Thanks in advance! All help will be greatly appreciated as I have no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed the sorting by difficulty, thanks to the help from @Robadob giving me ideas.

```
   case R.id.menu_order_difficulty:
        adapter.sort(new Comparator<Shop>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Recipe arg0, Recipe arg1) {
                return (difficulty(arg0.getDifficulty())-difficulty(arg1.getDifficulty()));
            }

            private int difficulty(String name)
            {
                if(name.equals("Easy"))
                    return 0;
                else if (name.equals("Medium"))
                    return 1;
                else if(name.equals("Hard"))
                    return 2;
                return 0;
            }
        });
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();             
        return true;
```

I thought I'd post my fully completed answer in case this helps anyone in the future.

Comment: Surely `return 3;` is never reached as to reach it all of these would need to equate false; `a>b` `a==b` `a<b` ?
You can reduce your whole if statement there to
`(difficulty(arg0.getDifficulty())-difficulty(arg1.getDifficulty())` it shouldn't matter that it may in future return values above or below +-1 as long as they stay positive/negative.

Comment: Thanks man, that works. I didn't really think of it like that. Cheers! I've edited my answer as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You want your comparator to be something like;

```
new Comparator<Shop>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Shop arg0, Shop arg1) {
            return nameToInt(arg0.getName())-nameToInt(arg1.getName());
        }
        private static int nameToInt(String name)
        {
            if(name.equals("easy"))
                return 0;
            if(name.equals("medium"))
                return 1;
            if(name.equals("hard"))
                return 2;
            return 3;
        }
    }
```

Using enums in your object to identify easy med hard could make this much cleaner.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help @Robadob. I used your example and expanded on it to create what I needed. I appreciate your help!